# git-hg cannot find mercurial module >= 4.6

Tags: git, mercurial

When I run `git-hg clone` I get the error message:

> Could not find a python interpreter with the mercurial module >= 4.6 available.  Please use the 'PYTHON' environment variable to specify the interpreter to use.

I have a PYTHON environment variable
[image]

And the same thing exists in PATH.

What is it looking for?

Comment: I think the key is the "with the mercurial module >= 4.6" based on https://github.com/frej/fast-export/blob/master/hg-fast-export.sh#L34

Comment: @StayOnTarget I saw that too but wouldn't figure out exactly what it was reading there. I thought I had python in all the right places.

Comment: I don't think its python itself that is missing, I think it is not finding the mercurial python modules...

Comment: I don't know exactly what it's looking for but "mercurial" and "mercurial-4.9-py2.7.egg-info" exist in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Try the `$python -c` command shown on those lines of the script, manually, for each Python command listed (`python2`, `python`, `python3` in that order) and see what error each one gives.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [mercurial module](https://pypi.org/project/mercurial/) made it for me:

```
python -m pip install mercurial
```